# Phonegap RemoteControls ios Plugin not working when device is offline

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, offline

I am using RemoteControls phonegap plugin on iOS to control playing audio while device goes to sleep (https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls) - great plugin !!

however - when the device is offline it does not work correctly … the audio title shows up as the full file path to the audio .mp3 rather than the 'title' passed to the plugin - this works fine when online.

It would seem the issue is down to the setting of the remoteImage - this is downloaded to the app to allow access offline but I use a 'Library no-cloud' location …. even if this is not set .. ie.  remoteImage = "" it will not display the title - only the fullpath ( which is very confusing to the user). Even when device is online but the image path points to the local file thumbnail path then it fails to display the title (again just the local audio mp3 file path) … and no thumbnail image.  But when online and the image points to a remote valid url image (even though the filepath to local audio .mp3 is the same) all works as expected.

I am no objective-c developer - but looking at the code it appears that it is expecting an image called 'no-image' when offline and can not find the thumbnail image path … but where should this be held ?  and regardless of whether an image is available or not should the plugin still function so that the title is the one passed from the app (same as when online) as this is only a string …. not a file path !!

Any help really appreciated - great plugin but need it to work same way when offline ….

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. The plugin doesn't function accurately (or as you expected) when the device is offline. The only way to fix this is to fix the code and build/release. If it's not your code, or you can't fix it, then the vendor/maker has too.  Contact them?